# Select items from JSON array using JsonPath where item does not contain a certain property

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonpath

I have a JSON file structure similar to this:

```
{
    "property1": 1,
    "property2": 2,
    "someArray": [
        {
            "item1": 1,
            "item2": 2
        },
        {
            "item1": 5
        }
    ]
}
```

All I want to do is to select the objects from the array which does not contain `item2` property. I'm using `NewtonsoftJson` and trying to do this thing using JSON path.

I managed to select the objects that do contain `item2` property, but I don't know the syntax to inverse the logic.

```
// Selects all the tokens where item2 property exists.
var tokens = jsonToken.SelectTokens("$.someArray[?(@.item2)]");
```

I tried using `!` in the filter part like this: `$.someArray[?(!@.item2)`, but it throws an error saying that `!` is unexpected character.

What should I do to invert the select logic here?

Working example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EICzl9).

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this approach. Hope it helps. [Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jeCCvl)

```
static string jonsString = (@"{
        'property1': 1,
        'property2': 2,
        'someArray': [
            {
                'item1': 1,
                'item2': 2
            },
            {
                'item1': 5,
                'item2': 2
            }
        ]
    }");

 var tokens = JObject.Parse(jonsString)["someArray"].ToObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>().Where(p=>!p.Keys.Contains("item2"));

        foreach (var token in tokens)
        {
           foreach(var item in token)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key +":"+ item.Value);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
item1:5
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way using JsonPath.

You can use LINQ on the JToken tree to do the filtering you want.
This is what JSON.Net uses under the hood when you perform a JSONPath query.

I would write the linq query like so:

```
(jsonToken["someArray"] as JArray)
.OfType<JObject>()
.Where(x => !x.ContainsKey("item2"));
```